# how to keep multiple spaces when appending

Tags: jquery, append

```js
let a = "<div class='child'>lorem       ipsum</div>";
$('#parent').append(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='parent'>
<div class='child'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

As yoy can see `a` is added but without multiple spaces.

How can I keep original number of spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Use `&nbsp;`

```js
let a = "<div class='child'>lorem &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ipsum</div>";
$('#parent').append(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put the content in a `pre` tag whose CSS is set to inherit the `font` styling from its parent:

```js
let a = "<div class='child'><pre>lorem       ipsum</pre></div>";
$('#parent').append(a);
```

```css
#parent pre {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='parent'>
<div class='child'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use non-breaking spaces in the string:

```
let a = "<div class='child'>lorem&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ipsum</div>";
```

Comment: This will add a `pre` tag in HTML and may break CSS or other javascript code

Comment: Possible, but unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

use HTML non-breaking space `&nbsp;`

```
let a = "<div class='child'>lorem &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ipsum</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a `textarea` element a remove all default styles, like this:

```js
let a = "<div class='child'><textarea>lorem       ipsum</textarea></div>";
$('#parent').append(a);
```

```css
.child{
  cursor: text;
}
textarea{
  border: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='parent'>
<div class='child'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```